# Ошибка 13 Permission denied при загрузке файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, permissions

друзья, у меня опять маленькие проблемки, нужна помощь)У меня в скрипте есть функция download_photos(url) , которая загружает сами фотографии по url из функции get_photos_by_Album:

```
def download_photos(url):
##пример url  =https://pp.userapi.com/c626723/v626723675/33436/KgAOM9KM690.jpg
r=requests.get(url).content     
filename=url.split('/')[-1]
for alb in Album_titles:
    if not os.path.exists('Pho/'+alb):
        os.makedirs('Pho/'+alb)
    with open('Pho/'+alb,'wb') as file:   
        file.write(r)

def get_photos_by_Album(Token,group_id,count=1000,offset=0):

all_Album_photos=[]
ids_photos=[]
ids_Albums=[]
group_photo_Albums=get_json("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getAlbums",{
        'owner_id':group_id,
        'count':count,
        'offset':offset,
        'need_system':1, 
        'access_token':Token,
        'v':5.73})

count_Albums=group_photo_Albums['response']['count']
group_photos_items=group_photo_Albums['response']['items']
Album_titles=[]
for album in group_photos_items:
    Alb_title=album['title']
    Album_titles.append(Alb_title)

for item in group_photo_Albums['response']['items']:
    id_Album=item['id']
    ids_Albums.append(id_Album)
    print(item['id'])

    photos_in_group=get_json("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get",{
        'owner_id':group_id,
        'album_id':item['id'],
        'extended':1,
        'offset':offset,
        'count':count,
        'access_token':Token,
        'v':5.73})
    count_photos_in_Album=photos_in_group['response']['count']
    fotki=photos_in_group['response']['items']
    all_Album_photos.extend(fotki)
    print('Kol-vo photos in album='+str(item['id']),len(all_Album_photos))
    print(count_photos_in_Album)
    if len(all_Album_photos)>=count_photos_in_Album:
        #break
        print('FINISH!!!')
    else:
        offset+=1000
    for item in fotki:
        id_photo=item['id']
        ids_photos.append(id_photo)

return all_Album_photos,count_photos_in_Album,ids_photos,ids_Albums,Album_titles
all_Album_photos,count_photos_in_Album,ids_photos,ids_Albums,Album_titles=get_photos_by_Album(Token,group_id)
```

Выдает ошибку, не знаю что делать с ней:

```
<ipython-input-1-26932eb9e094> in download_photos(url)
    98         if not os.path.exists('Pho/'+alb):
    99             os.makedirs('Pho/'+alb)
--> 100         with open('Pho/'+alb,'wb') as file:   ##bite write (bw)- 
побайтовая запись в файл
    101             file.write(r)
    102 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Pho/Фотографии со 
страницы Ирины'
```

Я читал, что надо попробовать запустить скрипт от имени админа, в командной строке пробовал, но увы. Также я просмотрел разрешения на ту папку,где лежит сам скрипт, и где будет создаваться папка Pho/, полный доступ и так был открыт.В общем жду вашей помощи комьюнити) Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Две трети кода можно убрать, как не относящиеся к вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

`'Pho/'+alb` - это папка, а вы открываете ее как файл.

Одно из возможных решений:

```
filename = "foto1.jpg"    
with open('Pho/'+alb+'/'+filename,'wb') as file:   
        file.write(r)
```

PS. Но для создания пути лучше использовать что-нибудь из модуля `os.path` (`join` или `normpath`).

Comment: Thnx,Эникейщик, респект) Все заработало как по-маслу! Просто у меня так скажем уровень скорее новичка-прогера) Спасибо еще раз, вообще классный ресурс stackoverflow)

Comment: Одно но, теперь скрипт загружает фото во все папки, даже если альбомы разные,а в идеале должен закачивать как на странице пользователя вк, т.е. если в первой папке 25 фото, то в 1 папку 25, а не все 1025 фотографий в первую и те же 1025 во вторую и т.д., как это реализовать?Заранее спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос и добавьте в него новый код. Нельзя исправить код, которого нет.